# How do I prove that a sequence of functions is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, proof-explanation, uniform-convergence

For $ n \in \mathbb N$

$f_n (x) = \frac{n^2 }{(x^2 +n^2)}$

Let $x \in \mathbb R $. Prove that $f_n (x) \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow  \infty$

My attempt: Let $\epsilon>0 $, then by definition of convergence $\exists N \in \mathbb N$  $\forall n\geqslant N$ : $| \frac{n^2 }{(x^2 +n^2)} -1 |< \epsilon$

$| \frac{n^2 }{(x^2 +n^2)} -1 | = |\frac {x^2}{(x^2 +n^2)}|< \epsilon$

Comment: Keep in mind that you are trying to $\textit{prove}$ convergence, not assume it. Thus, you yourself need to find what $N$ has to be in terms of $x$ and $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Do not assume $N$ exists, you have to prove it.
Your calculations are correct, anyways. Since $x$ is fixed, once you get to the last step you are basically done: you only need to find $N$ so that the last term is smaller than $\epsilon$.

To find $N$, observe that
$$
\frac{x^2}{x^2+n^2} < \epsilon \implies \frac{x^2}{\epsilon} < x^2 + n^2 \implies n> \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{\epsilon}-x^2}=\sqrt{\frac{x^2(1-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}}.
$$
So $N=\bigg\lceil\sqrt{\frac{x^2(1-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}}\bigg\rceil$ is enough.